# I want to be able to update a cell on different worksheet than the userform resides

Tags: excel, vba

I want to be able to update a cell on different worksheet than the userform resides.  Sheet1 has the userform.  I want ComboBox6 from the userform to populate cell a1 on worksheet "In House Sales Sheet."  I then want to print preview "In House Sales Sheet."

```
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''Print Preview
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()

   Sheets("In House Sales Sheet").PrintPreview

End Sub
```

Comment: A userform doesn't "reside" on any worksheet, what does "sheet1 has the userform" mean?

Comment: `Worksheets("In House Sales Sheet").Range("A1").Value = ComboBox6.Text`

Comment: All the cells that the userform writes to is on a sheet named Sheet1.

Comment: Thanks Mathieu!                               Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()

    Worksheets("In House Sales Sheet").Range("A1").Value = ComboBox6.Text


   Sheets("In House Sales Sheet").PrintPreview
    
End Sub  I put your code in here.  When I run it it gets stuck on the print preview.

Comment: You can *edit your question* if you have code to add.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm a noob here so I still have to learn the posting protocols.